# How to use game center on iOS 7 to create live matches?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, gamekit

Do you guys know any tutorial or code sample that covers using Game Center on iOS 7 for creating live matches?

All Apple sample codes are from 2011 (!) and their documentation is incomplete and vague and is also talking about iOS 6. All tutorials I found on the web are for iOS 6 and they don't cover live matches. Apparently Apple is not caring about that.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I just used the documentation on the apple website - its better than any tutorial (for understanding), though more verbose. The only thing outdated is instead of using an inviteHandler, you implement GKLocalPlayerListenerProtocol, and assign the listener after authenticating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back when I was working on game center stuff I used this Sample application developed by Apple for my references. I couldn't find it on their site anymore but it looks like some kind person hosted it on github for you!

[GKTank Sample Project](https://github.com/sdrazin/GKTank.git)

I'm not sure how much of this has changed since iOS7 but I highly suggest this as a start

Comment: no problem, I hope they've avoided making too many changes to the game center logic